# How can I have different functions in one button with tkinter python

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I am trying to make a research button with different sql functions.
The problem is that the button is working with only one sql function, no more.
Here is my code for my button :

```
research_button = Button(app, text="Rechercher", command=lambda:[self.surface_result(), self.eppaisseur_moy_result()])
            research_button.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
```

Here is my code for my functions :

```
def surface_result(self):

        cursor.execute("SELECT helicopter_surface_mouille FROM Helicopter")
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        for x in row:
            surface_result_label = Label(app, text=x, background = 'white')
            surface_result_label.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W)

def eppaisseur_moy_result(self):

        cursor.execute("SELECT produitp_epaisseur_moy FROM ProduitP")
        row2 = cursor.fetchone()
        for x in row2 :
            epaisseur_seche_moy_result_label = Label(app, text=x, background = 'white')
            epaisseur_seche_moy_result_label.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W)
```

The first function is working but not the 2nd one and i have an error :
mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found

Answer (score 0):

OK, i just found the solution :

```
cursor = mydb.cursor(buffered = True)
```

That will execute all of the fonctions without any errors :)